# How to generate a concatenated primary key on CSV import (MariaDB / MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, triggers, composite-primary-key

I import past invoices from CSV files into a MariaDB (MySQL) table.

The invoice `id` is built on other fields:
`client-order[variant][-subinvoice]`

eg. `0123-5c-0`

Until now, the values for `id` were computed batch with this SQL query:

```
UPDATE invoices SET
id = CONCAT (client,'-',
             order,
             IFNULL(variant,''),
             IF(subinvoice IS NULL, '',CONCAT('-',subinvoice))
             );
```

Because the `id` column is now PRIMARY KEY, I **need to convert the above query to a trigger** that generates the `id` "on the fly" when data from the CSV records are injected.

**Here's one possible solution.**
(User P. Salmon who helped me debugging my code ; thanks to him!)

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS invoice_generate_id//
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_generate_id 
BEFORE INSERT ON invoices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT (new.client,'-',
         new.order,
         IFNULL(new.variant,''),
         IF(new.subinvoice IS NULL, '',CONCAT('-',new.subinvoice))
         );
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with this , you cannot have and if..else..end if as part of a concat statement-  You need a SET statement to set a NEW.value and I suspect client,variant and subinvoice should be preceeded by NEW. Also you may be able to do this as part of the load data infile statement - see manual where it refers to variables. –

Comment: Thank you. You were absolutely right. I updated the code with a valid one based on your suggestions and the syntax that my batch SQL query was using. N.B. When creating the trigger, phpMyAdmin mentions an error at the semicolon that ends the `SET()` statement. One just has to ignore it as the trigger is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trigger that is syntactically ok. Note the use of coalesce

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS invoice_generate_id//
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_generate_id 
BEFORE INSERT ON invoices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  set NEW.id = CONCAT (new.client,'-',
             new.order,
                 coalesce(concat('-',new.variant,''),''),
                 coalesce(concat('-',new.subinvoice,''),'') 
                 )
    ;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your trigger that is syntactically ok. It was a great help. The use of coalesce is elegant. For `variant` we should avoid the surrounding `concat` if refering to my original example (because the variant was not prefixed by a hyphen). For `subinvoice`, I kept IF() and CONCAT() functions because they make the code easier to understand if I read the code again after several month, although I must admit that COALESCE() is more elegant.